# asp.net core IdentityServer 4 not persisting grant with safari

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, blazor-client-side

I have an asp.net core blazor wasm application which uses identity 4 for authentication. It is setup accordingly to the visual studio and deployed to an azure app service. When I use this on windows via Edge it works as expected, I can log in and see a new entry in the table PersistedGrants and I can login with multiple computers without issues.

When I know login from either safari on a Mac or any browser on an iOS device (since they all use the same browser engine) the whole PersistedGrants table is deleted. As far as I can see it doesn't matter if I log in with the same user who already has a grant or another one, all entries are removed.
The login process return in all cases a success.

In terms of packages I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer 3.1.4 and the Release versions of Blazor.

My startup:

```
...
services.AddDbContext<ISupportToolContext, SupportToolContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<ApplicationIdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SupportToolContext>();

        Log.Information($"Identity Server Key Type loaded: {Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Key")["Type"]}");

        services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, SupportToolContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(LOCKOUT_DURATION);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = MAX_TRIES_BEFORE_LOCKOUT;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // Email Settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        });

        // Configure LifeSpan of Identity email tokens
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(IDENTITY_TOKEN_DURATION);
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = UNAUTHORIZED_STATUS_CODE;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
        ...
```

and the ClientSide Programm.cs:

```
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        builder.Services.AddBlazoredModal();
        builder.Services.AddI18nText();
        builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

        // Service registration
        ...

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ApplySupportTool.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
               .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

        // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
        builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("ApplySupportTool.ServerAPI"));

        builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
        builder.Services.AddOptions();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

and in the index.html:

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

Can anyone point me towards what that can be or how I can find out more?

Comment: could be due to this:  https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2020/03/26/apple-safari-now-blocks-all-third-party-cookies-by-default/  There are some odd workarounds here: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/342

Comment: Okey, the problem is, that my website has multiple domains assigned. specifically ".ch" and ".com". For IS I use the .ch so as soon as I access over the .com domain this issue occurs - probably because of the isse @pcalkins posted.